# Laravel 5.4 passing undefined (yet) variable to another model's table

Tags: php, laravel

Could you please help me to handle this.

Controller:

```
  $ad = Ad::create([
    'title' => request('title'),
    'body' => request('body'),
    'cat_title' => $cat->title,
    'price' => request('price'),
    'city' => request('city')
  ]);

  $cat = Category::create([
    'title' => request('category'),
    'slug' => str_slug(request('category'), '-'),
    'ad_id' => $ad->id
  ]);
```

I'm getting an error  - Undefined variable: cat - obviously? Since the $cat variable is not yet defined on the time of being requested? But how could I handle this? And generally - am I doing it pretty much right?

My ad belongsTo category, and category hasMany ads.

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that you're creating $cat after you're using it for $cat->title  instead do it this way.  Set $cat->title to request('category), or set it to blank, and run $ad = Ad::find( $ad->id ); $ad->cat_title = $cat->title; $ad->save();

Comment: Ok, I just made it like so - 'cat_title' => request('category') - and it works. Not sure how much logic in what I'm doing, but so far seems ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are executing your 2nd portion after the insertion of the ad so, you can wrap it inside a condition something like this.

```
 // Execute this portion if above statement executed succesfully.
 if (!empty($ad->id)) {
   $cat = Category::create([
      'title' => request('category'),
      'slug' => str_slug(request('category'), '-'),
      'ad_id' => $ad->id
   ]);
 }
```